# Why does Rust require generic type declarations after the "impl" keyword?

Tags: rust

Defining the methods of generic type requires adding generic types after `impl`:

```
struct GenericVal<T>(T,);
impl <T> GenericVal<T> {}
```

I feel that removing `<T>` seems OK:

```
struct GenericVal<T>(T,);
impl GenericVal<T> {}
```

Is it any special consideration?

Comment: For anyone else wondering the same thing, check out my article [here](https://dev.to/talzvon/rust-generic-types-in-method-definitions-4iah) where I try to explain why this is required with simple examples.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Rust allows you to write `impl` blocks that apply only to some specific combination of type parameters. For example:

```
struct GenericVal<T>(T);

impl GenericVal<u32> {
    fn foo(&self) {
        // method foo() is only defined when T = u32
    }
}
```

Here, the type `GenericVal` is generic, but the `impl` itself is not.

Thus, if you want to write an `impl` block that applies for all `GenericVal<T>` types, you must first *declare* a type parameter on the `impl` itself (otherwise, `T` would try to look up a type named `T`).

```
struct GenericVal<T>(T);

impl<T> GenericVal<T> {
    fn foo(&self) {
        // method foo() is always present
    }
}
```

This declaration also lets you have a single type parameter that can be used multiple times, forcing the types to be the same.

```
struct GenericVal<T, U>(T, U);

impl<V> GenericVal<V, V> {
    fn foo(&self) {
        // method foo() is only defined when T = U
    }
}
```

Comment: However it seems that the compiler can infer from the type parameters of `GenericVal` instead of `impl`. Could you explain why the `impl<V>` syntax is a *must*?

Comment: I don't think it's strictly necessary, but if helps prevent ambiguities. What if someone introduced a type named `V` in the scope of that module? Is the use of `V` in the `impl` referring to the concrete type `V` (like the first example in my answer) or to an implicit generic parameter `V`?

Comment: @yeshengm as Francis said impl can be used to implement for specific types, you can think signature impl<T> GenericVal<T> {} like impl<T> is a declaration and GenericVal<T> is the usage for that declared type.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the following: why the compiler knows it is a generic type when seeing `<T>` in the struct, but in the `impl` all of a sudden the compiler doesn't know what the `<T>` is, and you have to type an additional `<T>` to tell it.

Comment: @powerseed Just because a type is generic doesn't mean that you want the impl to be generic as well, or maybe you want an impl that's generic in a different way. It's the same deal when you reference a type in a function signature: if a function accepts a `GenericVal<T>` for any `T`, then the function must be generic in `T`. And the type parameter doesn't have to be named `T` on the function (likewise on impls).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-02-traits.html#using-trait-bounds-to-conditionally-implement-methods

Note the `impl<T> Pair<T> {}` vs `impl<T: Display + PartialOrd> Pair<T> {}` part.

The generic type declaration after `impl` allows us to add more trait boundaries (`Display + PartialOrd` in this case) to the generic type `<T>`, and to define different methods respectively based on that.